# WaitCommEvent does not return on startup (works when COMPort is initialized via MatLAB)

Tags: c++, serial-port

I got an odd problem regarding  WaitCommEvent.
I open a serial port via C++ using CreateFile.
When I want to receive sth from it, WaitCommEvent does not reply and the programm crashes.
BUT: If I initialized the same Port with MatLAB and then try to open it with my C++ File it works perfectly fine.
Unfortunatley I was not able to find a solution in other Posts.
Would highly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

This is my C++ CODE (the values for comport and baudrate are right and the same as in the matlab code):

```
m_hLaunchpad = CreateFile(COMPORT_LAUNCHPAD, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

unsigned char buffer[64];
DCB dcb;
DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
DWORD dwCommModemStatus;
if (m_hLaunchpad == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return (C_ERROR);
}

if (!GetCommState(m_hLaunchpad, &dcb))
    return (C_ERROR);
dcb.BaudRate = BAUD_LAUNCHPAD; //baudrate; 
dcb.ByteSize = 8; //8 data bits
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY; //no parity
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT; //1 stop
if (!SetCommState(m_hLaunchpad, &dcb))
    return (C_ERROR);
SetCommMask(m_hLaunchpad, EV_RXCHAR | EV_ERR); //receive character event
WaitCommEvent(m_hLaunchpad, &dwCommModemStatus, NULL); //wait for character

if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR)
    ReadFile(m_hLaunchpad, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), &dwBytesTransferred, 0); // read and save in buffer
else if (dwCommModemStatus & EV_ERR)
    return (C_ERROR);
```

This is how the Comport is initialized via MatLAB:

```
% LaunchPad for potentiometers
handles.ser2 = serial(handles.COMPort2, 'BaudRate', 115200);
handles.ser2.BytesAvailableFcnCount = 64;
handles.ser2.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte';
handles.ser2.BytesAvailableFcn = {@instrcallback, hObject};
```

More info: I use a  Maestro and a Launchpad. Opening the Port and sending data to the Maestro Port works perfectly fine on startup and after the matlab code was executed, so only receiving from the Launchpad causes trouble.

Comment: You are ignoring the need to specify how the handshake signals are supposed to be used.  Matlab would not make that same mistake.  A device generally won't send anything when you don't turn on the DTR and RTS signals.  And WaitCommEvent() will stall forever if you don't set any timeouts either.

Comment: ty, I added the dcb settings for the hardware handshake, I also had set CommTimeouts (just was not posting those above). It still does not work.  Would highly appreciate more ideas. Using overlapped also did not do the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the solution.
It had nothing to do with async or handware handshake.

To set the Baudrate I used BAUD_115200 (from WinBase.h), and it seemes to be wrong.
I put in the Baudrate as an int (115200) instead of using the variable and now it works. I changed nothing else in the code.
For the Mini Maestro the variable BAUD_9600 does work though.